# I have an error with Backlogs plugin in Redmine

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

Since last week, I have a problem using `redmine_backlogs` plugin in Redmine. When I try to log time on an issue, I have this error message:

*an error occured, please check the server logs (Unprocessable Entity)*

Checking `production.log`, I have these lines:

`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Temps passé n'est pas valide):
  plugins/redmine_backlogs/lib/backlogs_activerecord_mixin.rb:38:in journalized_update_attributes!'
  plugins/redmine_backlogs/app/models/rb_task.rb:138:in update_with_relationships'
  plugins/redmine_backlogs/app/controllers/rb_tasks_controller.rb:28:in update'
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in sudo_mode'`

Here are the information about my Redmine instance:

```
Environment:

  Redmine version                3.4.5.stable

  Ruby version                   2.2.4-p230 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

  Rails version                  4.2.8

  Environment                    production

  Database adapter               Mysql2

SCM:

  Subversion                     1.9.3

  Mercurial                      3.7.3

  Git                            2.7.4

  Filesystem                     

Redmine plugins:

  a_common_libs                  2.1.10

  clipboard_image_paste          1.10

  global_roles                   2.1.0

  google_analytics_plugin        1.0.0

  redmine_backlogs               v1.0.6

  redmine_code_review            0.7.0

  redmine_dmsf                   1.5.7 devel

  redmine_drafts                 0.2.0

  redmine_issue_templates        0.1.1

  redmine_ldap_sync              2.0.8.devel.gf831737c23

  redmine_my_page                0.1.10

  redmine_scm                    0.5.1

  redmine_xls_export             0.2.1.t9
```

Thank you for your help

Mathieu

Comment: Probably time format is not valid. What exactly did you change in past 3 weeks? Did it work before?

Comment: Nothing changed in past weeks!!! That's why I find this issue really strange